# when using php mail getting smtp error from php mail

Tags: php

i am getting the following error when send from php mail.
and check it on dedicated server whm panel in mail report.

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 552 5.2.0 x65edFfCOsf8z :: ded :: Message rejected for spam or virus content :: Please include this entire message when contacting support :: v=2.1 cv=I8bFPIUg c=1 sm=1 tr=0 p=MTd1msIjAAAA:8 a=sU2ElePL1fh+zoELtCh9/Q==:117 a=L9H7d07YOLsA:10 a=9cW_t1CCXrUA:10 a=s5jvgZ67dGcA:10 a=8nJEP1OIZ-IA:10 a=AmzWBoANEAQA:10 a=lpJG3BmS9rEA:10 a=2JCJgTwv5E4A:10 a=m-bnlgmZlx0A:10 a=EnUgvIxqE1YA:10 a=2oKOZG5bAAAA:8 a=ZmejEW-fsLYoZ2jFqGIA:9 a=oJI5IDrX3K-v2epM:21 a=R-9hM1EI3jsEmhP7:21 a=thd3Pqr6jx6EN8yW:21 a=wPNLvfGTeEIA:10 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=3C1QSb0jjt0A:10 a=kcEQE9vDxJwA:10 a=ngyOktuYw20A:10 a=3UfFLR44nQwA:10 a=has7Mf9E4wwA:10 a=hOgrCEPG9TA63oEbKpNN:22 a=B7iUcy2KOd5iJp25KyqN:22 :: 100.00
```

can anyone suggest whats going wrong here.

```
$to="$email1";
$subject="$subject1";
$from = 'Pediatric Practice <mail@blkpediatricpractice.com>';
$message1 .= 'test';
$headers = "From: " .($from) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".($from) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ".($from) . "\r\n";;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
```

Comment: or email sending code is?

Comment: $to="$email1";
 $subject="$subject1";
 $from = 'Pediatric Practice <mail@blkpediatricpractice.com>';
 $message1 .= 'test';
 $headers = "From: " .($from) . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: ".($from) . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Return-Path: ".($from) . "\r\n";;
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
 $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";

Comment: put it nt he question so its readable

Comment: i have put there

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below link and configure your php file according to it.

https://www.codexworld.com/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-in-php/

Hope it helps!